# flatting out few hierarchal Options in scala

Tags: scala

I'm a bit lost with flatting out a case class that has a bunch of Option's.

My case class is Person, who looks like this:

```
case class Person(name: String, metadata: Option[Metadata])

case class Metadata(contacts: Option[List[Contact]])

case class Contact(id: Int, isAvailable: Option[Boolean])
```

what I want is to take an Option of Person and make a copy of that person but with contacts that  isAvailable equals true.

so if we have the below object:

```
Some(
Person(
  "John",
  Some(
    Metadata(
      Some(
        List(
          Contact(1, Some(true)),
          Contact(2, None),
          Contact(3, Some(false)),
          Contact(4, Some(true))
        )
      )
    )
  )
 )
)
```

the result would be:

```
Some(
Person(
  "John",
  Some(
    Metadata(
      Some(
        List(
          Contact(1, Some(true)),
          Contact(4, Some(true))
        )
      )
    )
  )
 )
)
```

how would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at quicklens: https://github.com/softwaremill/quicklens

It's going to be:

```
person.modify(_.metadata.contacts).using(_.filter(_.isAvailable == Some(true))
```

If you need to modify `Option[Person]`, you need to add `map`:

```
personOpt.map(_.modify(_.metadata.contacts).using(_.filter(_.isAvailable == Some(true)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Without external dependencies, something like this:

```
for {
  person   <- personOption
  metadata <- person.metadata
  contacts <- metadata.contacts
} yield Person(
  person.name, 
  Some(Metadata(
    Some(contacts.filter(_.isAvailable.contains(true)))
  ))
)
```